# Can anyone tell how to do multi-tenancy setup on OpenERP?

Tags: odoo, postgresql-9.1, multi-tenant

I am using OpenERP, i have over 5-6 domains and I would like to have a specific database associated with each domain. Can anyone know how to do multi-tenancy setup on OpenERP?

As I understand it, OpenERP has three application tiers: the database, the application server, and the web server.

If I want to create a working configuration for multiple, independent companies how do i do that ?

Comment: explain ........................

Comment: i have over 5-6 domains and I want to create database for each domain in single server using one OpenERP application.

Answer (score 2):

You can run each as a separate database on the same server and point all the domains to the same server.

To make sure that they only see their own database, you can add an option to the server startup:

`openerp-server --db-filter='%h'`

then it will search for a database with the same name as the domain

Comment: Where can i add that lines?

Comment: How did you install openerp? are you using windows or linux? When your openerp starts it calls the openerp-server executable. Go back to your installation guide and check where it is located

Comment: I installed using linux server